# I'm looking for a hebrew font

Tags: windows, fonts, hebrew

I'm looking for a (preferably free) hebrew font that the letter ח ("Chet"/"Ches") is shaped like the upper half of the letter "s" and is not a script font. The letter ל (lamed) should be shaped like a printed one, not have a loop on the bottom.

EDIT: The answer has been auto-selected by SU and is incorrect. Still looking...

Comment: But, umm, the letter 7et (ח, Chet) is not shaped like the upper half of the letter s - neither in the printed form nor in the handwritten form. It should be a pretty esoteric font. Can you attach an image of how you want it to look like? ... Oh, I see. it's 6 years later. By the way, I think you can un-accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a great list on [this site](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Hebrew.html) (TrueType fonts), most of them are free.

Otherwise, you have this [free project](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/), but only for Linux distributions.

Comment: Still incorrect. can the second link be ported to windows?

Comment: The fonts from Culmus are Postscript Type 1 fonts. MS Windows (from Win2000 onwards) supports Type 1 fonts, so you should be able to install the font files . You may need to convert from .pfa to .pfb first; use a font converter for this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontforge should work, for example.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no expert on the language, but [oketz](http://www.oketz.com) looks like it has [a few](http://www.oketz.com/fonts/all.html) that may suit your needs, all freely available.

Answer (score 4):

I use this for my work with researching in other languages with hebrew content: http://www.bibleworks.com/fonts.html - it is also free and has all characters that are needed.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a *particular* style of the font. I've seen that site before.

Answer (score 0):

Moshe - I'm not sure if the characters form the way you want to, but [here](http://www.pement.org/hebfonts.htm) is huge list of fonts that might help!